# Validate file input in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a custom validation for file input in Reactjs which checks validation for empty file input fields and display the message "please attach a file". On trying to attach a file, I get this error:

> invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React
>   child (found: [object File]). If you meant to render a collection of
>   children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-one.

Please, what could be the problem? I have researched this but all to no avail. Please, someone should help me out.

Comment: Error message is very clear, that means you are rendering the file object: **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object File])** inside render method. Update the code also, what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Fixed....I was doing e.target.files[0] instead of e.target.files[0].name.  Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

This mean you trying to render an object instead you should do something like:

```
let obj = { name: 1}

console.log(Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]))

render(){
  return (
    {
      Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])
    }
  )
}
```